# SSRS - Blank Pages (again...) even with respected settings

Tags: reporting-services

I know that the question was submitted a lot of times, but this is driving me mad.

I'm trying to make a landscape A4 report, printer friendly. As I could see in lots of threads before I tried to respect the fact that the body size must be inferior or equal to the physical page, including margins, and columns in the count.

Here are my document properties

Report:

[image: reportproperties1]

[image: reportproperties2]

Body:

[image: bodyproperties]

I inserted a first rectangle with some contents, at that point, no extra blank page, here is the rectangle location :

[image: rectangle1properties]

Right after I inserted a second rectangle with same dimensions as previous one:

[image: rectangle2properties]

Both first pages are rendered correctly with the rectangle at its expected location, but I get a 3rd extra blank page...

ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace property is set to true, and this did not help...

Do you have any trick to get definitely rid of these blank pages ?

Thanks a lot !

EDIT : Just added the report designer view, as requested

[image: reportdesigner1]
[image: reportdesigner2]

Comment: Could you maybe provide a picture of the design view? Also, have you removed any excess space between the bottom of the second rectangle and the bottom of the report?

Comment: Just added the two pictures below the original post. Even with the space removed between rectangle #2 and footer, I get an extra blank page after first rectangle, and a second extra page after second rectangle.

Comment: Your margin is set to zero.Try setting a narrow margin (say 10mm) and then reducing the width and height of the content by 20mm. Depending on your scenario, the renderer will look at the default printer settings and if zero margins are not supported, it will try to fit within the constraints of the printers limits. You could also try to reduce the width or height of the content significantly and if the blanks go away at least you'll know if the content height or width that;s the issue.

Comment: Tried this as well, but no luck... That's really not good, cause the product itself is really nice, to build the queries,etc, but when it comes to printing stuff...

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how I didn't notice it before, but your body height is bigger than your page height defined in the report properties. If your report is supposed to generate two pages, that second page will have to add an extra 3 centimeters and cause that third page.

[image]

Comment: So if I understand well, let's say I have 10 rectangles that must fit each one one page, I should stick the rectangles one to the other with no space between in the designer windows, and force a pagebreak after for each rectangle ?

Comment: Yes if that's the desired outcome. Any white space beyond the body height that gets left over can cause a blank page. So minimizing white space where possible should be done.

Comment: @GoreGonzola did my suggestion in the answer work to fix the issue?

Comment: @GoreGonzola Did my solution remedy the original issue with the blank extra page?

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to handle this the following way : I put my first rectangle 0,5cm under the header (with a forced pagebreak after) and if I use the same size of rectangle for everypage, ensuring that there's a 0,5 cm space between each rectangle, I can manage to display content on multiple pages, with rectangle bordel always located at the same position. Guess I should keep this method for all future reports :) Thanks a lot for your advices !